# xslt - how to create a variable with text content of space characters of a dynamically determined length that will perform well

Tags: variables, xslt, dynamic, text

I would like to create a variable that contains a text value that is a number of space characters but the number of characters is not known until runtime. This needs to be done a great many times so i would like to use something that will perform very well.

One option is substring() function on a previously declared node, but this limits the length to no more than that of the original text.

Another would be to use a recursive template with concat() function, but not sure about the performance implications.

What is a way to do this that will perform very well?

Comment: I am assuming you are using XSLT 1.0 . Let us know if otherwise.

Comment: shihpah, You may be interested in an efficient (both time and space) XSLT 1.0 solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a global variable of length say 4000 spaces. Then if the desired string is less than 4000 spaces, use substring(); if greater, use a recursive approach as outlined by Durkin. In 2.0 of course the code is much simpler to write but choosing an approach that performs well is still an interesting little problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion and divide and conquer. This will give you run-time cost of order (log N). Alternatively, if your XSLT processor implements tail-end recursion optimisation, then you can use a tail-end recursion solution for better safety at scale. Here are the two solutions...

### For non tail-end recursion optimising XSLT processors...

```
<xsl:template name="spaces">
  <xsl:param name="count" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$count &lt;= 10">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring('          ',1,$count)" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:call-template name="spaces">
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count idiv 2" />
      </xsl:call-template>  
      <xsl:call-template name="spaces">
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count - ($count idiv 2)" />
      </xsl:call-template>  
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

### For tail-end recursion optimising XSLT processors...

```
<xsl:template name="spaces">
  <xsl:param name="count" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$count &lt;= 10">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring('          ',1,$count)" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:text>          </xsl:text>  
      <xsl:call-template name="spaces">
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count - 10" />
      </xsl:call-template>  
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: sorry:
i am using XSLT 1.0 processor, so no `idiv` operator. So it seems, to replace line:
`<xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count idiv 2" />`
with:
`<xsl:with-param name="count" select="floor($count div 2)" />`
and to similarly replace other use of `idiv`, works instead. right?

Comment: Yes, your are right. I forgot `idiv` is only XSLT 2.0 . Your substitution `floor($count div 2)` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

**For an efficient (both time and space) XSLT 1.0 solution**, see this:

**http://www.sourceware.org/ml/xsl-list/2001-07/msg01040.html**